# My app is not compatible in all devices on google playstore

Tags: android

Hi my application in google playstore in not compatible with all of the devices and I don't know why. I uploaded other apps but this one is not compatible with all of them. I don't know if it's because of gradle or manifest but here's both of them..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.thesis2.kun.carkila"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/KGJsonConverter.jar')
compile files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.amigold.fundapter:library:1.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.6'
compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.thesis2.kun.carkila">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.mapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.kun.carkila.mapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="@android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.InsertActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_insert"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerhome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ownerhome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.TransactionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_transaction"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DetailActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.UpdateActivty"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_activty"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerhome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner_detail"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerhome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner_tabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.rentedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rented"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerAccept"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner_accept"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.UpdateClick"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_click"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_renter_tabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.acceptedCars"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_accepted_cars"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.AcceptedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_accepted"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ReSchedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_re_sched"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ReSchedClick"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_re_sched_click"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.toGPSActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_to_gps"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.GPSActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gps"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs" />
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.GPS_Service" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDD2Hq5hcbljKKvj2-fCRsbTq76ne8vD54" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- <meta-data -->
    <!-- android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" -->
    <!-- android:value="@string/google_maps_key" /> -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.GPSOwner"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gpsrenter"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.toGPSRenter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_to_gpsrenter"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.SearchResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/search" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.LocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerCurrent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner_current"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerStatus"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner_status"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DoneActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_done"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OAboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_oabout"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RAboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rabout"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OSafetyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_osafety"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RSafetyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rsafety"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverHome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DrvierRegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_drvier_register"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_detail"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverEdit"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_edit"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverTabs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_tabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.currentDriver"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_current_driver"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverTabs" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.driverStatus"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_status"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.drvrDoneActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_drvr_done"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.driverDone"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_done"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <service android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.FcmInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.FcmMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_oprofile"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.OTermActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_oterm"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rprofile"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RTermsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rterms"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ReportActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_report"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RenterTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.UserImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_image"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dprofile"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DTermsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dterms"
        android:parentActivityName="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverTabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ProfileEditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_edit"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.RPEdit"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.PaymentActivity1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_payment"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.downPaymentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_down_payment"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.driverCheck"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_check"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_image"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.UpdateUserImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_user_image"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ownerCheck"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner_check"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.Chat_Room" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.messagesActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.messagesActivity2" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.UpdateCarImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_car_image"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.renterCheck"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_renter_check"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.AcceptedRenter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_accepted_renter"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ResetPasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.driverOwnerActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.pastTransactionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_past_transactions"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ChangeForgotPassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_change_forgot_password"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ChangePasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_change_password"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverCarDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_car_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.DriverCars" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.ScheduleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.btcInstructions" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.calendarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.thesis2.kun.carkila.driverCalendar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is required permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />
```

So devices should have a camera to install your app

Comment: Moreover, there are still devices running API Level **10** (still supported by Google). And this `android:minSdkVersion="15"` prevents them to be compatible. Moreover, this requirement `<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />` is not supported by all the currently supported devices.

Comment: This helped me solve the problem. `camera2` is what keeping devices not compatible. I removed 2 and its okay now. Thakns :)